# Looping over variables and data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I have a data wrangling question, that I really cannot get my head around. I have come across data stuck together in one long string, with among other things names and gender of several individuals. I want to pick out specific pieces of information from these strings and put them together in a data frame. I have managed to do this, but my solution is far from elegant, and it would be nice if one could loop over variables and data frames instead of using my bulky solution. I cannot share the original data, but I have created an example data instead. Data follows the following structure:

```
df <- data.frame(Movie=c("Matrix", "Black Widow"), 
                 People=c("¤¤¤34543¤Keanu Reeves¤932 9273¤Male¤¤¤02734¤Laurence Fishburne¤936 2740¤Male¤¤¤47622¤Carrie-Anne Moss¤938 0722¤Female¤¤¤21539¤Hugo Weaving¤953 6124¤Male",
                 "¤¤¤98237¤Scarlett Johansson¤923 8734¤Female¤¤¤72367¤Florence Pugh¤732 4284¤Female¤¤¤55661¤David Harbour¤981 2469¤Male"))
```

And in the end, I would like to arrive to the following data frame:

```
#        Movie               Name    Sex
#1      Matrix       Keanu Reeves   Male
#2 Black Widow Scarlett Johansson Female
#3      Matrix Laurence Fishburne   Male
#4 Black Widow      Florence Pugh Female
#5      Matrix   Carrie-Anne Moss Female
#6 Black Widow      David Harbour   Male
#7      Matrix       Hugo Weaving   Male
```

Okay here is my solution:

I start by counting the occurrences of the separating characters, and then separate data into pieces:''

```
library(stringr)
df$people_count <- str_count(df$People, "¤")

max_people_count <- max(df$people_count)

new_varnames <- paste0("Name", 0:max_people_count)
df[c(new_varnames)] <- str_split_fixed(df$People, "¤", max_people_count+1)
```

I want to select column 1, 8, and 10 and rename column 8 and 10 to "Name" and "Sex". Then I want to select together with column 1 every 6th starting from column from column 8 and 10. My solution was to create new data frames, rename selected columns, and put everything back together in the end:

```
col_select <- c(8, 10)

df1 <- df[ , c(1, col_select)]
colnames(df1)[2] ="Name"
colnames(df1)[3] ="Sex"



col_select <- col_select+6
df2 <- df[ , c(1, col_select)]
colnames(df2)[2] ="Name"
colnames(df2)[3] ="Sex"

col_select <- col_select+6
df3 <- df[ , c(1, col_select)]
colnames(df3)[2] ="Name"
colnames(df3)[3] ="Sex"

col_select <- col_select+6
df4 <- df[ , c(1, col_select)]
colnames(df4)[2] ="Name"
colnames(df4)[3] ="Sex"


final_df <- rbind(df1, df2, df3, df4)

final_df <- subset(final_df, Name != "")  # remove blank lines
```

As you see, my skills in R are limited. There must be a way to do this in a loop. My problem is that I cannot create the names of the data frames in a working for-loop. If I could do that, I would not have to repeat the same lines over and over again, just changing the name of the data frame (note that my original data is much bigger).

I would really appreciate some help with this problem as I am struggling to learn how to use R in an efficient way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need an explicit loop.

In base R you can use `strsplit` to split the useful parts of each string into a vector once we have found the pattern of the unwanted characters in between. Each vector can then be converted to a data frame inside `lapply`. The resulting `list` of data frames can then be `Map`ped to the appropriate movie from your original data set. Finally, the resultant lists of data frames can all be joined together using `do.call("rbind", ...)`

```r
do.call('rbind',
  Map(\(x, y) cbind(Movie = x, y), df$Movie, df$People |>
    strsplit('¤¤¤\\d+¤|¤\\d+ \\d+¤') |>
    lapply(\(x) as.data.frame(t(matrix(x[-1], nrow = 2))) |>
              setNames(c('Name', 'Sex'))))) |>
  `rownames<-`(NULL)
#>         Movie               Name    Sex
#> 1      Matrix       Keanu Reeves   Male
#> 2      Matrix Laurence Fishburne   Male
#> 3      Matrix   Carrie-Anne Moss Female
#> 4      Matrix       Hugo Weaving   Male
#> 5 Black Widow Scarlett Johansson Female
#> 6 Black Widow      Florence Pugh Female
#> 7 Black Widow      David Harbour   Male
```

As you can see, this works for your example data frame. Such string parsing is highly dependent on the *exact* input however, so it's not clear whether this will work on your actual data.